# Center my dedication in my thesis

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script

Currently, I have

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     % Seitenformat
        12pt,                               % 
        bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis
        index=totoc,    % Index in das Inhaltsverzeichnis
        abstracton,     % mit Abstrakt
        headsepline,    % Trennlinie f�r die Kopfzeile
        %footnosepline, % Trennlinie f�r die Fusszeile
        ]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{calligra} % for dedication

\begin{document}    
\newpage

\vspace{4cm}
{\fontfamily{calligra}\selectfont \begin{huge}  To my parents, my brother and my sister. \end{huge}}


\newpage

\end{document}
```

I want to have this dedication in the middle of the page, but `\vspace` does not work, how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?  BTW I would write my sister first, then the brother.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,     % Seitenformat
        12pt,                               % 
        bibliography=totoc,     % Literaturverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis
        index=totoc,    % Index in das Inhaltsverzeichnis
        abstracton,     % mit Abstrakt
        headsepline,    % Trennlinie f�r die Kopfzeile
        %footnosepline, % Trennlinie f�r die Fusszeile
        ]{scrreprt}


\usepackage{calligra} % for dedication

\begin{document}    
\title{Title}
\author{Joe Doe}
\dedication{To my parents, my sister and my brother.}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: I thought about the ranking of brother and sister, why do you think sister is better first? Are there any rules?

Comment: @JenBohold This type of question is not really fit for TeX.SE; it has more to do with English than with TeX. You should post it on http://english.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 6):

use star with `\vspace`:

```
\vspace*{4cm}
```

Comment: Right.  `\vspace` allows space to be gobbled at the top (or bottom) of a page, the starred version does not.